# Java Nullpointerexeption, agenda não insere compromisso

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Tenho um projeto para a faculdade, uma agenda simples, sem partes gráficas ou banco de dados.

São quatro classes: Contato, Compromisso, Agenda e Teste. Nas classes Contato e Compromisso temos somente as variáveis básicas e seus construtores, getters e setters.Na classe Agenda temos os métodos inserir contato, inserir compromisso, excluir contato, excluir compromisso, listar contato e listar compromisso e a classe Teste é a classe principal.

Toda a parte de contatos funciona, mas a métodos inserir compromisso me retorna "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Código da Classe Compromisso.

```
public class Compromisso {

    private String data;
    private String descricao;

    public Compromisso(String data, String descricao) {
        this.data = data;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Compromisso() {
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

}
```

Código dos métodos Inserir Contato e Inserir Compromisso:

```
    private int qtdMaxContato = 100;
    private int qtdContato;
    private int qtdMaxCompromisso = 100;
    private int qtdCompromisso;
    private Contato[] Contato;
    private Compromisso[] Compromisso;  

    public Agenda() {
        this.Contato = new Contato[100];
        this.Compromisso = new Compromisso[100];
    }

    // Getters e Setters e outros métodos.

     public void InserirContato(String nome, String telefone, String celular, String email, String nascimento) {
        Contato novo = new Contato(nome, telefone, celular, email, nascimento);
        Contato[qtdContato] = novo;
        qtdContato++;
    }

    public void InserirCompromisso(String data, String descricao) {
        this.Compromisso[qtdCompromisso].setData(data);
        this.Compromisso[qtdCompromisso].setDescricao(descricao);
        qtdCompromisso++;
    }
```

Código classe Teste:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Agenda a1 = new Agenda();
        a1.InserirCompromisso("22/22/22", "testetestetestetestetesteteste");
        a1.ListarCompromisso();
    }
```

Esse erro acontece só no meu computador?
como eu resolvo isso?

Comment: Qual linha estoura o erro? Tem como postar o stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você está inserindo o compromisso, todos os items do array `Compromisso` são nulos, então a chamada a `this.Compromisso[qtdCompromisso].setData(...)` vai falhar com esse erro.

Você precisa criar o objeto para colocar no array antes de acessá-lo:

```
public void InserirCompromisso(String data, String descricao) {
    Compromisso novoCompromisso = new Compromisso(data, descricao);
    this.Comprimisso[qtdCompromisso] = novoCompromisso;
    qtdCompromisso++;
}
```

ou

```
public void InserirCompromisso(String data, String descricao) {
    Compromisso novoCompromisso = new Compromisso();
    novoCompromisso.setData(data);
    novoCompromisso.setDescricao(descricao);
    this.Comprimisso[qtdCompromisso] = novoCompromisso;
    qtdCompromisso++;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada, acabou sendo só falta de atenção, rs :)